# MVC 5 app - facebook app redirects to the wrong URI - redirect_uri=http instead of redirect_uri=https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, load-balancing

I have an app in facebook developer.
This app is configured with a "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"-value with a URL with http**s**.
But when I click on the Login with facebook button on my page facebook redirects me to the http version of the URI. This seems like a facebook bug in their OAuth module?

Comment: It's possible but unlikely that it's a bug, otherwise everyone's https redirect would be failing - what code are you using to create this behaviour?  [Even their examples show redirect_url being set to https:// values](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

Comment: I'm using a default MVC 5 Application with Facebook authentication using the default MVC 5 templates for the latest VS2013 update.

Comment: Apparently this could be due to the website sitting behind load balancers at the web hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue when I deployed to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with SSL terminated at the load-balancer. In this case, the request received from the load-balancer by the server looks like the client is connecting with HTTP, and the OWIN providers incorrectly infer that the URL Facebook/Twitter/Google needs to connect back into your site should use HTTP instead of HTTPS on the public side of the load-balancer.

I couldn't find a simple solution to this, there didn't seem to be any parameters to override the URI protocol which gets stored in the `IOwinRequest.Scheme` property. In the end, I grabbed the source code for the [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) project, and the source code for the [ASP.NET Identity](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/) project, and I hacked it around a bit so that I had local projects in my solutions for:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter

There was 50 or so other projects within Katana that I left out - I made all of these other dependencies Nuget package references to the official versions.

Then I found every reference to `IOwinRequest.Scheme`, and I replaced it with a snippet of code that also looked for the [X-Forwarded-Proto](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto) header that is injected by the load-balancer when using SSL offloading.

Something like this:

```cs
var scheme = Request.Scheme;

if (string.Equals(Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    scheme = "https";
}

// Use the scheme in the construction of a URI...
```

If your load-balancer or proxy server doesn't provide the X-Forwarded-Proto header, then your options are pretty limited. You could re-encrypt the traffic and send it on to your server using the same protocol it came in on.

Comment: I switched hosting to azure and there you don't need any hacks to get your app working. I would suggest considering switching hosting provider.

Comment: Azure must be using SSL end to end. You can do that on AWS too, but it's nice if you can offload it to the load balancer for performance reasons. On AWS, if you offload SSL, you can also use the AWS Certificate Management service to get a free wildcard cert issued by Amazon. This saved me nearly $500 annually - and AWS takes care of updating it automatically in future. Definitely think that OWIN should support this better - maybe it does and I just don't understand the code base well enough ;-)

Comment: Actually I take back what I just said since I haven't enabled the load balancer feature in my Azure subscription. I assumed it was enabled by default with my current subscription plan but I think you have to manually upgrade the subscription to take advance of this feature. So if I do that then my app could stop working. Just to be clear: The same app had issues with the SSL/load balancer (which was enabled by default) on my old hosting provider but in Azure it worked right away with the standard Azure subscription. Will have to dig deeper into that.

Comment: Same thing happens with Cloudflare using the Flexible SSL option